# MSAL iOS build with Carthage - linker error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, azure-ad-msal

I'm following the instructions here (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc) to add the MSAL library to my (new) project. I'm using Xcode 10.1. I have a `Cartfile` with just one entry for `MSAL`. When running `Carthage update --platform iOS` I get a linker error (lots of them actually):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_MSID_DEFAULT_FAMILY_ID", referenced from:
      -[MSALAccountsProvider accountForHomeAccountId:error:] in MSALAccountsProvider.o
      -[MSALAccountsProvider accountForUsername:error:] in MSALAccountsProvider.o
      -[MSALAccountsProvider allAccountsForAuthority:error:] in MSALAccountsProvider.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MSIDConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MSALAccountsProvider.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MSIDTelemetryBaseEvent", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MSALTelemetryDefaultEvent in MSALTelemetryDefaultEvent.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MSIDAADV2IdTokenClaims", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MSALResult.o
```

And so on - many such symbols.

Interesting the `macOS` one builds for me, even though on Github `MSAL` says `macOS` is not supported :)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us how your `Cartfile` looks? (more specifically, are you using a specific version of MSAL?). For comparison, I just tried creating a new iOS project and added a `Cartfile` with this one line `github "AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc" "master"`. I then ran `carthage update --platform iOS` and it seemed to work, code was downloaded and built at least.

Comment: I copied the `Cartfile` from the `active-directory-ios-swift-native-v2` project and it turns out the `Cartfile` was pointing to `dev` which won't build for me (dunno why) :( Changing that to `master` worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome, glad you got it working :)